# How to change formatting of timestamp using ctime?

Tags: c

I am new to C, and trying to figure out how to generate timestamps from the system time and use that timestamp to name a file. So far, I've had success with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t rawtime;  
    time(&rawtime);

    printf("%s",ctime(&rawtime));
    
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is correct.

```
Wed Apr 12 14:51:03 2023
```

Now, my question is how can I change the formatting of this timestamp to something more file-name friendly such as

```
MM_DD_YY_HH_M_S
```

Comment: Behold: [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime).

Comment: You want [`strftime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)

Comment: @tadman thank you for this! could you give an example on using this? the example in the link is...daunting.

Comment: It's daunting for a reason, as there are many subtle differences between the various formatting choices, like 12h or 24h, but there are *innumerable* examples out there as this tool has been around for a long, long time. It's worth noting there are examples even on the `man strftime` documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to change formatting of timestamp using `ctime`?

Standard library function `ctime()` does not provide for format changes.

---

Instead, use `gmtime()` (or `localtime()`) and `strftime()`.

```
struct tm *tm = localtime(&rawtime);
if (tm) {
  #define TIME_STRING_SIZE 100
  // MM_DD_YY_HH_MM_SS
  #define TM_FMT "%m_%d_%y_%H_%M_%S"
  char time_string[TIME_STRING_SIZE];
  size_t size = strftime(time_string, sizeof time_string, TM_FMT, tm);
  if (size > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", time_string);
  }
}
```

Using local time risks generating the same MM_DD_YY_HH_MM_SS for 2 differed times on the 25-hour day the local time zone goes from daylight savings time to standard time.

---

I'd recommend using universal time, not local time, and follow [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like format: year-month-day

```
struct tm *tm = gmtime(&rawtime);
if (tm) {
  #define TIME_STRING_SIZE 100
  // YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS
  #define TM_FMT "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"
  char time_string[TIME_STRING_SIZE];
  size_t size = strftime(time_string, sizeof time_string, TM_FMT, tm);
  if (size > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", time_string);
  }
}
```